# prove or disprove this theorem about subsequences

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to prove or disprove that for a certain sequence $a_n$, if the subsequence of the even indices and the subsequence of the odd indices are Cauchy sequences then $a_n$ converges.

Answer (score 4):

It is not true. Take, for example,
$$
a_n=\begin{cases}
0,&\quad\text{if $n$ is odd};\\
1,&\quad\text{if $n$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$